# The difference: It's or It is

Tags: grammar

When you use 'it is', sometimes it is contracted, and other times two words are fully prounced.
Is there a meaning for this difference?

1. It's
2. it is

Comment: Both of them is same but sometimes "it's" may refer to "it has".

Answer (score 3):

They both means the same thing, however the contraction is usually considered more informal.